# PySpark type hinting for returning a Column (expression)?

Tags: python, testing, pyspark, type-hinting

How do you type hint that a function will return a PySpark Column type?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
def get_some_filter_expression(col_string_name) -> TODO:
    return F.col(col_string_name)
```

I included a dummy example above, and I am trying to figure out what **TODO** should be.

**EDIT:** I guess the reason I had this question was because I was assuming that PySpark "column types" under `spark.sql.types` could be used for type-hinting. This is not the case. In case it is a common confusion, I will leave this question as is. See the answer of LiamFiddler below.

Comment: Have you tried `from pyspark.sql import Column`, then `def func() -> Column:`?

Comment: This was not intuitive to me, but yes this was the answer I was looking for. If you create this as an answer I will upvote and close. I looked for the answer at `pyspark.sql.functions` and `psypark.sql.types` and Googled for a while. Could not find it. Forgot to look into `pyspark.sql`. Thanks! @LiamFiddler

Comment: I feel ya man, I'm getting used to PySpark right now, and the amount of time I'm spending in documentation and Googling is insane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import Column, Functions as F
def get_some_filter_expression(col_string_name) -> Column:
     return F.col(col_string_name)
```